# How much freedom do I have in character theory?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I have reached the end of a course in representation theory (just an introduction), and I am just doing some examples of finding character tables.

The way I generally do it is to guess a representation and find its character. Assuming I've done well and get an irreducible, I then want to use this and the trivial character to make a new representation (which may or may not be irreducible).

My question is: What can I do with two representations to get new ones?

I know that you can multiply by linear characters. Can I add and subtract to get what I want?

Comment: You can *always* multiply two characters to get another one - the result just won't typically be irreducible. But you might be able to figure out how it decomposes into irreducible characters.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Can I always add / subtract? The trouble I'm having is seeing what these operations correspond to on the representation's end.

Comment: Assuming your two representations have the same dimension, where does their sum send the identity of your group?

Comment: @pjs36 I would have thought we are talking about a direct sum, so, to the identity? Otherwise, probably not to the identity...

Comment: Adding characters corresponds to direct sum, so you won't get any new irreducible characters that way. If you have a reducible character, and some of its irreducible components, then you can subtract them off.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein That makes more sense, thanks. I have to use the fact that you *can* add, in order to do subtraction. Is there a way of knowing if an irreducible is a component of a given one (Just by looking at the numbers in the character table)?

Comment: Yes, you use the inner product for that. The rows of the character table form an orthonormal basis with respect to the inner product, so you can determine how many of each irreducible character shows up in an arbitrary character.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks, I think that the last point you made was where my confusion was.

Comment: Don´t forget that if $\chi$ is an irreducible character then so is $\bar{\chi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you are allowed to do:

- Multiply characters (corresponds to tensor product)
- Add characters (direct sum)
- Take complex conjugate of characters

Then you can use these facts and known representations to subtract and break down characters.

To see if a known irreducible character is a factor of another character, use the inner product and orthogonality laws.